# Error en la carga de imagenes HTML y JS

Tags: javascript, html

He programado mi primera web y es una especie de tienda online. Lo que pasa es que las fotos que he usado las he tenido que modificar para que su tamaño no sea el que no debe ser, todo esto con JS.

El problema que tengo es que, almenos en mi ordenador, de vez en cuando se carga antes la página que el archivo JS o de repente se me descontrola todo y las imagenes de los productos se desubican. Os dejo la web para que podáis verlo, a ver si os pasa, recargando la página. Os recomiendo entrar en la sección de Gafas de Sol, allí es donde se ve mejor: https://www.ravestate.es

El archivo JS lo tengo en el body, a bajo de todo, y dentro de él tengo el código dentro de

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
        ...
    })
});
```

Alguna idea de cuál es el problema?

Muchas gracias.

PD: Si modificáis el tamaño de la página sí se pone bien.

Comment: Cuando pones que se desubican, ¿te refieres a que se te superponen textos con imágenes, no? E imagino no están exactamente donde quieres, imagino.

Sería necesario ver más código, para ver como has hecho para colocar las cosas, a mi parecer esto tiene pinta del CSS (recuerda que para que entendamos bien tu CSS, necesitamos tu html).

Comment: Por qué no defines el tamaño con CSS? Es más sencillo ajustar las imágenes así

Comment: porque mejor no usas bootstrap?

Comment: El código que tienes en main.js nunca se está ejecutando, porque declaras la función pero no la invocas. Si le estuvieras modificando algún atributo a las imágenes via JS, lo verías como un estilo "inline" o en linea. Verás que nada de eso se está aplicando, si seleccionas el div con clase .img o el elemento img en si. Adicionalmente, debes explicar mejor cómo percibes que se "descontrola todo". La página (o el paseo del HTML siempre ocurre hasta el momento que el documento encuentra el script, en donde para para bajarlo y ejecutarlo, y luego continua, a menos que sea un `<script>` descargado